# Como ignorar primeira linha de arquivo csv

Tags: php

Estou precisando ignorar a primeira linha de um arquivo que estou importando em csv com o php, essa primeira linha é um cabeçalho, alguma dica de como posso fazer isso?
Tentei fazer um contador, mas não consegui resolver, o que tenho é isso:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
    $Dados = file($tempFile);

    foreach($Dados as $RegLinhas) {

        // RETIRA ESPAÇOS NO INÍCIO E FIM
        $Linha = trim($RegLinhas);
        // DIVIDE A STRING
        $CamposImport = explode(';', $Linha);
        $IdPessoa = $CamposImport[0];       
        $Nome = $CamposImport[1];
        $IdUnicoop = $CamposImport[2];
        $DataAdmissao = $CamposImport[3];
        $IdCargo = $CamposImport[4];
        $LotacaoRH = $CamposImport[5];
        $CTPS = $CamposImport[6];
        $CTPSSerie = $CamposImport[7];
        $CTPSUF = $CamposImport[8];
        $DataNascimento = $CamposImport[9];
        $CPF = $CamposImport[11];

    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes fazer o seguinte para remover o primeiro item de array, [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array_shift):

```
...
$Dados = file($tempFile);
array_shift($Dados); // remover primeira linha, primeiro elemento do array
...
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/l1aJyk)

Apesar de a maneira acima ser a mais simples/melhor, aqui fica uma maneira sem usar função:

```
...
foreach($Dados as $key => $RegLinhas) {
    if($key == 0) continue; // saltar para a prox volta caso seja a primeira linha
    ...
}
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/X2vguC)

Comment: Olá @Miguel, dica espetacular, muito obrigado, as duas formas funcionaram.

Comment: @adventistapr ainda bem. Boa sorte